# Controlling layers displayed in data driven pages of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

I am trying to use data driven pages to show four different pages.

All of these have the same extent, so the extent of the index layer is the same in each case.

What I want to do is show different layers in each page.

So for example page 1 would show an extent from bottom left hand corner British National Grid (200000, 300000) to top right hand corner British National Grid (300000, 400000) showing the layer "RED_CIRCLE".

Page two would show the same extent;
bottom left hand corner British National Grid (200000, 300000) to top right hand corner British National Grid (300000, 400000), showing the layer "BLUE_SQUARE".

I have found a lot of tutorials online but these all only show how to use tools to set up data driven pages that all have different extents.

How can I achieve this control of layers in each page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having looked into this, you can do this through page definition queries.

1. Add a field to each layer that specifies the page on which it should display. e.g. for Red_Circle open the attribute table and add field "Page". This field name must match the field name used in the index layer of your data driven pages.
2. Edit this field to contain the page number, e.g. Page_1. These pages numbers must match those used in the index layer.
3. Open the properties of the layer. Go to "Definition Query". Select "Page Definition" and enable. Set Page Name Field to the correct field (e.g. "Page") and select "Show Features that Match".

This will then cause that latyer to only show on page 1.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution.  It is using page definition queries in a way that I have not used them.  I'm assuming that you are using an index layer that is four identical overlapping polygons.